# jhipster 4: How to Update to Own Needs

Tags: angular, webpack, jhipster

After generating a new jhipster project with Angular 2+ and creating an entity:

I want to disable that the user can create an instance of my entity. Therefore as a first start I deleted in the file 
`src/main/webapp/app/entities/book/book.component.html` the following html code:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary float-right create-book" [routerLink]="['/', { outlets: { popup: ['book-new'] } }]">
 <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
 <span  jhiTranslate="jhipsterApp.book.home.createLabel">Create new Book</span>
</button>
```

But still the button is displayed in the system - probably as it is still visible in `target/www/app/main.bundle.js`.

What are the proper steps to update the Angular 2+ frontend? Do I miss another generator step?

Answer (score 1):

Doing angular changes have to be done by executing

```
npm start
```

This ensures that `webpack` updates the referring target files.

My error was to start the project just with

```
./mvnw
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do not forget to disable this function on the backend too, or allow only with admin role, with adding the @Secured annotation.

Comment: Yes, for sure. This is just _for a first start_